# Hide "edit.php?post_status=wc-completed&post_type=shop_order" in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have tried without success to hide from people in our office that does not have admin privileges the `edit.php?post_status=wc-completed&post_type=shop_order` from the orders page in Woocommerce.

I have attached a snap shot of the section that I am wanting to hide:

Orders Completed and cancelled:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.